# Oracle apex Grid Counter Negatives

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
--To get count of Gemba This week
With Target_Count as     
(Select Position,
Count(Monday) + Count(Tuesday) + Count(Wednesday) + Count(Thursday) + Count(Friday) + Count(Saturday) + Count(Sunday) as Week_Total  
From Gemba_Data
  Where Shop_Area = :P300_SELECT_AREA
  AND Calendar_Week = :P300_CALENDAR_WEEK
  AND Calendar_Year = :P300_YEAR Group by Position
  )

select ROWID,
       POSITION as Position_Value,
       (Select Required_Frequency From Gemba_Required Where Position = Gemba_Data.Position) as Required_Frequency,
       **(Select Target_Week From Gemba_Required Where Position = Gemba_Data.Position) - (Select Week_Total From Target_Count WHERE Position = Gemba_Data.Position ) as Gemba_to_Target**,
       (Select Required_hidden From Gemba_Required Where Position = Gemba_Data.Position) as Required_hidden,
       COMMENTS,
       Monday,
       Tuesday,
       Wednesday,
       Thursday,
       Friday,
       Saturday,
       Sunday
  from GEMBA_DATA
  

  Where Shop_Area = :P300_SELECT_AREA
  AND Calendar_Week = :P300_CALENDAR_WEEK
  AND Calendar_Year = :P300_YEAR
```

Hello I am working on an interactive grid in oracle apex where there is a column that is made up of two columns subtracting from one another it takes a count of all the info entered in for that weeks row and subtracts that number from the other, however they have a target of 7 sometimes info is entered by multiple people or multiple times this causes the counter to go below 0 I need a way to counteract that, If I add a minimum value to the column in APEX I get an error when the code subtracts to -1 so I need a way to do it in SQL any help is greatly appreciated.
[image: Example of Current Grid]

Comment: This does not look like an editable interactive grid. Is the data entered via a form ? It might be helpful to explain the business flow in a bit more detail

Comment: It is editable just only the highlighted boxes, the person puts their initials when the job is done and then the counter column on the righ subtracts by 1

Comment: I don't understand how your form works (please provide a basic example, just enough the reproduce the problem instead of your entire project), but normally you'd capture this with a validation. In interactive grid you can do row by row validation. just validate the input so the calculated value stays positive ?